# How to Union child collections from their parent entities in EF?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I have multiple "parent" entities, each with a navigation collection of children.

For a given subset of parents, is there a neat and efficient way of creating an IEnumerable of all the children? (i.e no duplicates).

I can foreach through the parents and Union the children, but this seems very inneficient.

```
from p from parents
select p.Children
```

returns duplicates.

```
class Parent
{
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

class Child
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var query = (from p in parents
             from c in p.Children
             select c)
            .Distinct();
```

Comment: Maybe you still have to create a custom comparer class implementing IEqualityComparer that the Distinct really filters the entities.

Answer (score 2):

Or with method syntax:

```
var children = parents.SelectMany(p => p.Children)
                      .Distinct();
```